# send request from server to wpf client application

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc, wcf, msmq

I have application in WPF that checks new data for every minute.

We are maintaining this interval from the website so the user can change the interval time from the website.

I want to change that interval time for the application running on the client's pc when it is changed from the website.

How can I do this?

Comment: How can I send http request to wpf application?

Comment: You'll need to listen for such requests on a port. Check out something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From MSDN:

> The Socket class provides a rich set of methods and properties for network communications.

You can see some examples [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/socket-send-receive/).

Comment: but socket is keeping only one connection